# Question regarding linear functionals

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the following exercise:

Consider $X := C[0,1]$ and let $f_0(x) := 1-2x$. Find at least two linear functionals with norm one such that $l(f_0) = 1$.

I tried to solve that with brute force (i.e. trying around with examples like $l(f) = f + 2x$) but I couldn't come up with appropriate solutions. I would be really thankful for a systematic approach.

Comment: Think about the Riesz representation theorem - linear functionals on $C[0,1]$ can all be represented as integration against a certain measure. Try finding some integral-based linear functionals that fit the requirements.

Comment: Also, note that the example you gave is _not_ a linear functional (its range is $C[0,1]$ again, not the base field $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Let me get that right: Riesz representation theorem tells us that for every continuous linear functional $l \in X^{*}$ we have $g \in X$ such that $l(f) = \langle f,g \rangle \ \ \forall f \in X$ and $||l|| = ||g||$. For $X = C[0,1]$ we have $\langle f, g \rangle = \int_{[0,1]} f(x)g^{*}(x)dx$ which means we need to find an appropriate $g$ with $||g|| = sup |g(x)| = 1$ and $l(f_0) = \langle f_0, g \rangle = \int_{[0,1]} f_0(x) g^{*}(x) dx = 1$.

Comment: Continuous linear functionals on $C[0,1]$ are of the form $f \mapsto \int fd\mu$. You will find this theorem in Rudin's RCA.

Comment: @csch2 Rudin first considers positive linear functionals only for the sake of simplicity. He then goes to continuous linear functionals also.

Comment: Yes, I looked it up and found the other version of the Riesz Representation Theorem (RRT). My problem is just that in our course we defined the RRT explictly for Hilbert spaces $H$, so I was completely unfamiliar with your "new" RRT. The question is from Teschl's linear and non-linear functional analysis, chapter 4.2, problem 4.15. The chapter treated the Hahn-Banach-theorem and several corollaries. So I think I am supposed to use that for my solution?

Comment: What about the functional $f\mapsto f(0)$?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Surely that is one choice. A second choice seems a bit difficult.

Comment: @geetha290krm Yes, I missed the part where the OP mentions that he'd like to have 2 functionals, sorry. Though, we could probably take $f\mapsto (f(0)-f(1))/2$.

Comment: That settles it. More generally, $ f \to tf(0)+(1-t)\frac {f(0)-f(1)} 2$ works for every $t \in (0,1)$. @SeverinSchraven

Comment: @geetha290krm Well, surely this gives infinitely many solutions, but it is not really systematic, is it?

Comment: The trick is to show that $\int |1-2x|d\mu(dx)|<1$ if $\mu$ is not concentrated on $\{0,1\}$. That proves the only choices of $\ell$ are the one's I mentioned.  @SeverinSchraven

Comment: @geetha290krm The functional $\ell(f)=-f(1)$ is not part of your family. But, yes, apart from that I agree.

Comment: My argument is that only a linear combination of $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ can work.

Comment: @geetha290krm I got that you meant that :) that is why I wrote that I agree with you. Also, you should write an answer about the uniqueness part as this was your insight, not mine (I do not intend to claim credit for something which I did not come up with).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** This is more of a long comment than a real answer as it does not make use of a systematic approach.

Here are two possible choices of functionals. Note that $\Vert f_0 \Vert =1$ and thus, in order to show that the functionals or normalized, we only need to show that their norm is bounded by $1$.

We consider $\ell(f)=f(0)$. This functional is linear and normalized. Indeed, we have
$$\vert \ell_1(f)\vert =\vert f(0) \vert \leq \Vert f \Vert$$
and
$$ \ell_1(f_0)=1-2\cdot 0=1 $$

Secondly, we have the functional $\ell_2(f)=(f(0)-f(1))/2$. We have
$$ \vert \ell_2(f) \vert =\vert f(0)-f(1) \vert/2 \leq (\vert f(0) \vert+f(1)\vert)/2 \leq \Vert f \Vert $$
and
$$ \ell_2(f_0)=((1-2\cdot 0)-(1-2\cdot 1))/2=(1+1)/2=1. $$

**Added:** An easier choice would be $\ell_3(f)=-f(1)$. The point is that we are looking for points where the $\vert f_0\vert$ equals $1$. As geetha290krm pointed out in the comments, this gives us an infinite family of functionals with the desired properties via $\ell=t \ell_1+(1-t) \ell_3$ for $t\in [0,1]$.

Comment: Only a linear combination of $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ can have these properties.  We can use Riesz' Theorem to prove this point.

Comment: Thank you! Excellent answer for me.

Comment: @user1265841 Thanks. However, geetha290krm makes an excellent point and I hope he'll turn it into an answer for people to upvote. Essentially his idea tells you how to do things in a systematic fashion and why we end up with those functionals.